# What is the C# Equivalent of java's transient keyword?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer to serialize an object to JSON, but there are some fields within the object which don't need to be serialized. In java I would mark them with the 'transient' keyword. Is there an equivalent keyword or standard practice in C#?

Comment: Read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4881/A-Comparative-Study-of-Java-and-C and search to transient in the web page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute on the property and it will not be serialized.

See: [ScriptIgnoreAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx)